ASP.Net Using Data in Array to Populate HTML Map Areas Tooltips and Data Captions Using ImageMapster
I have an HTML page which reads the data from a data array in an ASP.Net controller.  The data is used to create map areas which will then show the data as a tooltip and also fill caption boxes.  I have successfully created the areas using a modified version of the code on the ImageMapster Beatles Menu page:
<img id="mainmap" src="/images/1641Map1.jpg" style="width:879px;  height:1557px" usemap="#main-map">
 @foreach (var item in Model.Areas)
{
<area shape="rect" data-full="@item.Name" data-name="@item.Name,all" coords="@item.Left,@item.Top,@item.Right,@item.Bottom" href="#"  />
}
<div style="width:390px; height: 120px; font-size: 12px; ">
<div id="1641-caption" style="clear:both;border: 1px solid black; width: 400px; padding: 6px; display:none;">
    <div id="1641-caption-header" style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 12px;"></div>
    <div id="1641-caption-text"></div>
</div>

The following Javascript is where I am having trouble.  This is fixed and does not read from the data array provided:
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("ready")
});
var inArea,
    map = $('#mainmap'),

captions = {
        area1: ["Area 1 Caption", "Area 1 Text"],
        area2: ["Area 2 Caption", "Area 2 Text"],
        area3: ["Area 3 Caption", "Area 3 Text"],
        area4: ["Area 4 Caption", "Area 4 Text"],
    },
//When mouse moves over individual areas:
single_opts = {
    fillColor: '000000',
    fillOpacity: 0.1,
    stroke: true,
    strokeColor: 'ff0000',
    strokeWidth: 2
},
    //When mouse moves over image:
    all_opts = {
        // fillColor: 'ffffff',
        fillColor: '000000',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        stroke: true,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeColor: '000000'
    },
    initial_opts = {
        mapKey: 'data-name',
        isSelectable: false,
        singleSelect: true,
        fill: true,
        mapkey: 'id',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        fillColor: 'ff0000',
        clickNavigate: true,
        showToolTip: true,

        onMouseover: function (data) {
            inArea = true;
            $('#1641-caption-header').text(captions[data.key][0]);
            $('#1641-caption-text').text(captions[data.key][1]);
            $('#1641-caption').show();
        },
        onMouseout: function (data) {
            inArea = false;
            $('#1641-caption').hide();
        },
        areas: [
            {
                key: "area1",
                toolTip: "Area 1 Caption"
            },
            {
                key: "area2",
                toolTip: "Area 2 Caption"
            },
            {
                key: "area3",
                toolTip: "Area 3 Caption"
            },
            {
                key: "area4",
                toolTip: "Area 4 Caption"
            }
        ]
    };
opts = $.extend({}, all_opts, initial_opts, single_opts);
map.mapster('unbind')
    .mapster(opts)
    .bind('mouseover', function () {
        if (!inArea) {
            // Registers mouse move over image
            map.mapster('set_options', all_opts)
                .mapster('set', true, 'all')
                .mapster('set_options', single_opts);
        }
    }).bind('mouseout', function () {
        if (!inArea) {
            map.mapster('set', false, 'all');
        }
    });

The array being read contains the Name (the name of the area), Left, Top, Right, Bottom, plus the actual data that I would like to display.
Hunting around for an answer I've changed the table data from an array to an IEnumerable and then am using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert the IEnumerable to something that would, I hoped, do the correct conversion:
captions = @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.IndexeAreas1641)));
alert (captions);

this does not cause any errors but I am not getting the lines that then attach the data to the captions to work - $('#1641-caption-header').text(captions[data.key][0]); produces nothing. The alert following this added code shows [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], which appears to be like the working examples.  What is missing, and how can I effectively debug this?

Hunting around for an answer I've changed the table data from an array to an IEnumerable and then am using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject to convert the IEnumerable to something that would, I hoped, do the correct conversion:  captions = @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.IndexeAreas1641)));  this does not cause any errors but I am not getting the lines that then attach the data to the captions to work - $('#1641-caption-header').text(captions[data.key][0]);, produces nothing.
